# Creating a Flipboard compatible RSS Feed

Tags: rss, rss-reader, flipboard

Has anyone managed to do this?

I've tried using .Net's `SyndicationFeed` and I've tried the most simple static page. I've read various guidance on what Flipboard is looking for and I've even tried those published examples.

The feeds are valid, but if I type the full URL into Flipboard it will read the feed title and allow me to add it, but in all cases it shows no posts. Just an empty feed.

Wordpress.com seems to work just fine of course, and I've tried copying the output from that. I'm starting to wonder if flipboard requires the content to be google searchable or something. My content is in development, so isn't of course SEO listed, but I've made a few feeds publicly addressable to no greater effect.

Here's an example of the simplest, valid, static feed I've tried;

```xml
<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Sample feed</title>
    <link>http://localhost:2089/rss</link>
    <description>sample description</description>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <copyright>(C) 2012</copyright>
    <item>
      <link>http://localhost:2089/rss?id=1</link>
      <title>title 1</title>
      <description><![CDATA[
        <html><body>helo world</body></html>
      ]]></description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Using the firewall logs on various tests I've confirmed that Flipboard isn't looking for any other resources other than this (and other samples of) XML, but I don't know if it's looking for stuff elsewhere on the web before it will download content.

Does anyone know the key piece of a Flipboard compatible RSS feed or protocol?

[Update]

Looking at the firewall logs, it looks like the Flipboard doesn't connect directly to the resource URL but goes out to AWS over 443, presumably these are the Flipboard servers, and the request comes from their browser proxy. It reads my feed, but by the time Flipboard returns it, it's blank.

Comment: Did you work out what the requirements were in the end? I'm still fighting it...

Comment: Not yet, no but I haven't looked at it recently.

Answer (score 0):

Flipboard [has a page](https://flipboard.com/rss/) with details about what they need to make your RSS feeds look nice in their application.

I do indeed believe that for performance reasons Flipboard polls the feeds from their server rather than from the app directly, which explains why you see AWS IPs in your logs.

Comment: It's a nice page, but inconsistent: at the start they state they support "Media RSS: Assets such as images, video, and audio are included using this standard extension to RSS." and then later on: "<media:content> tags ARE NOT SUPPORTED."...